# SQL generate string from splitting another

Tags: sql, delphi

I have a number of corrupt Dates in an Advantage database, but luckily I have a reverse date field which is intact.

I need to use SQL to recreate the Date field in the form 'DD/MM/YYYY' from the RDate string 'YYYYMMDD'.

Something equivalent to:

```
UPDATE table SET Date = FormatDate('DD/MM/YY',StrToDate('YYYYMMDD',RDate))
```

I don't know if this is possible to select character positions and use variables this way in SQL or if I'll have to write a program (in Delphi) to do the operation.

Thanks

Comment: You should never be storing your dates as strings, it's just asking for localization problems later on.

Comment: With Oracle/MS SQL Server something along those lines is possible with SQL... I don't know Advantage DB to answer the question... just wanted to say: make a backup of that table before attempting such a big correction/change in data

Comment: If it's just a one-time-job, don't bother looking for unusual SQL syntax. Just walk the table from a Delphi program and update all that needs updating.

Comment: @Seph The Expiry Date is a Date(4) but the RExpiryDate is a Char(8). What do you mean by localization problems? My Delphi apps tends not to have trouble converting between the two. Though we do have the odd unexplained corruption to the RExpiryDate, I've presumed through the record being in use during a power surge or cut.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like

```
update table set
  date = cast(substring(rdate, 5, 2) + '/' +
    right(rdate, 2) + '/' +
    left(rdate, 4) as date)
/* where ... */
```

(assuming your connection's date format setting is the default `'MM/DD/YYYY'`)

Comment: +1 The substring approach will work. I'm unclear as to whether he's storing as a string or date.  Seems like trouble to have the column named "date".

Comment: The field names are actually named "Expiry Date" and RExpiryDate but this substring approach is throwing the 7200 error on the cast: Unexpected token: ( : found extra tokens after expected end of statement - Location Of Error: 39

Comment: That looks like syntax error. Could be my mistake, or your typo... Check the [manuals](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?key=32).

Answer (score 0):

TOndrej I'm not sure if it was a syntax error or if cast is not recognised but I achieved the desired result with the following SQL:

```
update members set "Expiry Date" = ((substring(RExpiryDate,7,2)) + '/' + (substring(RExpiryDate,5,2)) + '/' + (substring(RExpiryDate,1,4)))
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: So the cast isn't necessary? Seems like Advantage does an implicit cast. Welcome, I'm glad I could help.

Comment: If this works, then the "Expiry Date" is stored as a string, which is why casting as date didn't work.

Comment: @ChrisThornton You're right Chris I testing this in to another field which was a string. It doesn't actually convert it in to a Date. I'm still unsure how to do this...